# Paradoxical Friction When Frying Eggs

Tags: fluid-dynamics, friction

I cook scrambled eggs for breakfast in an 8-inch diameter non-stick frying pan with sloping sides (approx 45 degrees).  I cook the eggs in a lot of butter and bacon grease that is melted firest, so there is very little friction between the eggs and the frying pan.  About half way through my cooking time, I spin the eggs to make sure they haven't stuck to the pan.  I spin the eggs by swirling the frying pan in a horizontal plane, with my left hand, in a clockwise direction.  For a reason I can't figure out, the eggs always rotate counter-clockwise in response to this.  I have reversed the direction, swirling the frying pan counter-clockwise with my right hand, and the eggs then slowly rotate clockwise.  The eggs slightly ride up on the sloping sides, but otherwise remain flat in the bottom of the pan.  I have tried to keep the roation at as constant a speed as I can to make sure I'm keeping the torque constant in case some asymmetry is introduced.  I'm really puzzled.

Can anyone explain how the eggs feel a rotational torque in the opposite direction of the rotation of the pan?

Comment: Have you tried this experiment in the Southern Hemisphere?

Comment: they rotate in the opposite direction relative to the pan, but relative to you (or the burners, let us say) too?

Comment: Are you tilting the pan?

Comment: @brucesmitherson yes, they rotate relative to my stationary kitchen.

Comment: @Wutaz no, the pan is horizontal all the time.

Comment: @userLTK  I would, but I don't know how to cook eggs standing on my head.

Comment: I think (joking aside), Bruce's comment is good, but probobly not accurate cause you're not actually spinning the pan but stirring in the plan.   The angular momentum of or any liquid inclines it to stay still, and resist the spinning, but it should generally go in that direction.  The 100% answer is kind of hard to say without actually seeing a video but one possible explanation - The eggs might be spinning with your stirring on the bottom, and due to some kind of circulation pattern, spinning in the reverse direction on top.  But, I wouldn't swear to that, just a possibility.

Comment: A video would certainly be useful so I'll try and get one posted to look at.   An accurate description of the motion of the pan is a swirling motion in the horizontal plane.  No tilting or twisting, constant speed.  The eggs have solidified into a flat 8" diameter, 1/2 inch thick, flexible but solid disk.